# how to get selected drop down list item from grid view in asp.net 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net

i 'm working with grid view. here i just want to add one feature that admin can change the value from drop down list. here is my grid view design :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="status_name">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbut_sortstatus1" runat="server" CommandArgument="status_name" CommandName="Sort" CssClass="normaltext" Font-Bold="true" Text="Status">
        </asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="placeholderstatus1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_StatusList1" runat="server" DataTextField="status_name" DataValueField="Id" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="True" onselectedindexchanged="DDL_GroupList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID ="DDL_StatusList1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />  
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hd_status" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("status_name") %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

and here is my code :

```
    protected void GV_ViewUserList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
          if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
           {
                DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.Cells[7].FindControl("DDL_StatusList1");
                HiddenField hdValue = ((HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("hd_status"));
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem item1 = ddl.Items.FindByText(hdValue.Value.ToString());
                if (item1 != null)
                {
                    item1.Selected = true;
                }
                DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)e.Row.Cells[8].FindControl("DDL_GroupList1");
                HiddenField hdValue1 = ((HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("hd_group"));
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem item2 = ddl1.Items.FindByText(hdValue1.Value.ToString());
                if (item2 != null)
                {
                    item2.Selected = true;
                }
            }
        }
      }
```

what should i do wrong here...

please help me..

Comment: "It's not working" - the most unhelpful phrase you could use. What is not working? What should it be doing? What it is doing that it shouldn't be.  Help us to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple use this technique :

```
DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DDL_StatusList1");
            ddl.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem,"status_id").ToString();
            if (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "group_id").ToString() != "")
            {
            DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DDL_GroupList1");
            ddl1.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "group_id").ToString();
            }
```